# how to debug this android program

Tags: android

when i am trying to run a simple android application in netbeans 6.9.1 i am getting the below error:

```
**Creating output directories if needed... 
Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources... 
Compiling aidl files into Java classes... 
compile: 
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:361: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds 
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Documents and Settings\JiggleVostro1310\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\FTPClient\bin\classes 
Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Documents and Settings\JiggleVostro1310\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\FTPClient\bin\classes.dex... 
=C:\Documents was unexpected at this time. 
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:449: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:199: apply returned: 255 
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)**
```

Can anyone explain me what this means and how to resolve this. I am new to android applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that there's a bug in the Ant scripts somewhere and something isn't properly handling path names that contain spaces. Try moving your project to a directory outside `My Documents`, to somewhere like `C:\AndroidProjects\FTPClient`.

Answer (score 0):

**=C:\Documents** makes me think you have a bad setting somewhere. One of two things is likely happening:

1. That equals sign before the path is causing the failure.
2. A path is specified somewhere which requires being wrapped in quotes but isn't, because of the space in the path (ex: should be "C:\Documents And Settings...")

I would check your build properties and paths, as well as any included JAR files or Library projects for a small typo.